# Sumifs with Dates in plain text not working

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to sum revenue for november.  Dates of transactions are stored in plain text like this '10-11-2022'.

| Date | Revenue |
| --- | --- |
| 10-11-2022 | $10 |
| 11-11-2022 | $11 |

I am using this formula:  sumif(A:A,"*-11-2022",B:B)

It is returning 0

I know there are problems around dates, but this exact approach is working in a different google sheets file, just not the one I'm working on.   Please help me figure out why.

I've also tried manually entering the word 'Nov' in a separate column that is also plain text and using that in the formula, and that also doesn't work.

Comment: Perhaps they are true date.

Answer (score 0):

assuming amounts are also in plain text:

```
=SUM(FILTER(SUBSTITUTE(B2:B; "$"; )*1; MONTH(A2:A*1)=11))
```

[image]

Comment: That does work thank you - but any clues as to why the way I'm doing it is not working - or rather how to fix it so it does? My exact approach is working on other google sheets docs and even on another tab in the same google sheets file, so ideally I'd like to keep things simple.

Comment: BTW - the amounts were stored as numeric values so don't need the substitute.  I'm guessing that since the month filter works, Google sheets is really storing these as date values rather than text strings, but I can't see a way to actually fix that

Comment: @GilesS can you share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output?